# Programatically undeploy web application from server

Tags: web-applications, deployment

Is it possible to programatically undeploy web applications(WARs specifically) from server. If the answer is yes, is the way to undeploy different for different servers.

I am specifically looking for undeploying from following servers

- Tomcat
- JBoss
- Jetty
- GlassFish
- Websphere
- Weblogic
- Geronimo
- Resin
- JOnAS

I know it may be a long answer if the way to undeploy is different across different servers. In that case I am more than happy to get some generic solution or pointers for this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandeep,

I'm not aware of a standard, in-container way of one web-application undeploying another. My instinct is that the apps themselves are "contained" and the spec doesn't intend for them to manage their container.

That said, most / all of these web containers provide APIs for deploying and undeploying web applications. The approaches are not common though, and when my development colleagues create a new integration for our [uDeploy](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/deploy/) product, we have to research each in turn. For instance, with Tomcat you can use the Tomcat Manager APIs. You could use the open source Apache Ant tasks as an example of what you want to do: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant

For Websphere, you are probably are writing jython scripts or doing some of your own programming against the JMX APIs. Weblogic is somewhere in-between as it provides some nice Ant scripts you could borrow, as well as direct APIs.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "undeploy", but if you have SSH access to the web servers, you can install Git source control management to "toggle" different versions of a web app regardless of the web server in question. For example, say you have two Git branches: 1) "production", and 2) "offline". the production branch would contain the production version of the web app. The "offline" branch could contain only one file , e.g., index.html that tells users that the site is "down for maintenance" or what have you.

You switch branches with:

```
git checkout production
```

or

```
git checkout offline
```

and git automatically swaps out all the files in the file system and the web server never knows the difference. You can write a shell script to do this and even assign it as a cron job to happen at a scheduled time if you want to.

Be aware that you will kill all user sessions when you do this, so you will want to do this at planned intervals or after notifying users.

You can find everthing you need to need to use git here: http://git-scm.com/

Comment: By undeploy I meant properly removing the webapplication from the server and doing necessary cleanups. For example in tomcat this may be simply deleting application folder or .war file from webapps directory(though I am not sure if that is the right way and it properly unregisters it)

Comment: As you said in your post, you will have to handle specific requirements for different web servers in your script and I can't give you specifics for Tomcat. But if the webapps folder is part of your git repository, checking out a different branch that does not contain the .war file, effectively deletes the file from the file system. You can also mix in any other file system operation/command within the "undeploy" .sh script, i.e., you would not be limited to just git commands.

Comment: Hi tqheel thank you for your answer and sorry for not making myself clear. Actually I am looking for a java way to do it. Giving a broader picture, I would have a main webapplication deployed on server and many other small web applications, which will be used in the main web application as plugins. I want to give administrator of the main webapplication to undeploy these small web applications(which i would put it as plugins) by just clicking a button from the UI